# Selecting rows based on column contents which are in a list in kdb

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I have a list called 'A' as:

```
     cont
     "aa"
     "bb"
      "cc"
```

I have a table called 'run' containing columns

```
      first    second     third
      sad      random      "aa"
      happy    random1     "dd"
```

I have to select those rows from 'run' where the column third contains elements in list A. I'm very new to kdb and any help on how to do this is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the keyword [`in`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/search/#in) which allows you to check if the values in one list appear in another:

```
q)show A:("aa";"bb";"cc")
"aa"
"bb"
"cc"
q)show run:([]f:("sad";"happy");s:("random";"random1");t:("aa";"dd"))
f       s         t
----------------------
"sad"   "random"  "aa"
"happy" "random1" "dd"
q)select from run where t in A
f     s        t
-------------------
"sad" "random" "aa"
```

If `A` is an unkeyed table, then you can pull the column `cont` out using `` A`cont ``:

```
q)show A:([]cont:("aa";"bb";"cc"))
cont
----
"aa"
"bb"
"cc"
q)select from run where t in A`cont
f     s        t
-------------------
"sad" "random" "aa"
```

When using `in` the output is a boolean list, equal in count to that of the argument on the left (`1 2 3` in this case):

```
q)1 2 3 in 2 4 6
010b
```

Use of the [`where`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/select/#where) clause in the [`select`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#select) statement filters the rows returned. Applying `where` to boolean list returns only the indices where it is true:

```
q)where 1 2 3 in 2 4 6
,1
```

And by extension, only these indices would be returned from the table.

It should also be noted that even though the table you have provided is only an example it contains the keyword [`first`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/select/#first) as a column header. Keywords as headers should be avoided if possible as they will cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I'm getting the following error using 'in'
(incompatible lengths (different lengths of operands for synchronized operation or table columns lengths are not the same)

Comment: the table 'A' has some header name too.  Is the error due to this?

Comment: Added an example for if `A` is a table, where you need to pull the column `cont` from it. Additionally the order of the arguments for `in` matters, the columns from the table should be the first argument (`third`) and the comparison list should be the second (`A`).

Comment: I generated A using selecting a column from another table.
Further the column third has type C

Comment: The updated method should work, by using `select` the variable `A` above is a table. You can return a list instead of a table by using `exec col from tab` instead of `select`.